# How were Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans made?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, food

Is anything mentioned in the series that could explain how [these](http://www.hawkin.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/E35693_800.jpg) 'sweets' were made?

Comment: I'll guess that there may be magic involved.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bertie_Bott's_Every_Flavour_Beans

Comment: Is there a particular reason to assume that they aren't made in precisely the same way as mundane jelly beans?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### By accident

The Chocolate Frog Card included with the Hasbro Chocolate Frog Candies included a bit about the genesis of the 'sweet'.

> [image]
>   Bertie Bott
>   Inventor
>   Bertie Bott was born in 1935. He invented Bertie Bott’s Every Flavor Beans quite by mistake. His original purpose was to create tasty candies from food. He accidentally included a pair of dirty socks in his experiment!

However, there is no evidence that Rowling wrote the cards for the Hasbro candies. Some of them [don't even fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxwQx.jpg) with Rowling's characters.

Rowling [is known](http://web.archive.org/web/20100205161409/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=96) to have written the cards in the Chamber of Secrets video game, but those cards don't really give much inforamtion about the candy.

> [image]
>   Bertie Bott
>   1935-present
>   Inventor of Bertie Bott’s Every-Flavour Beans.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the case of Gwenog Jones a contradiction between two non-canonical sources? Neither the cards nor the films were written by Rowling.

Comment: @Adamant - Gwenog Jones appears in Rowling's Daily Prophets from the 90's as well as the ones from 2014. She generally is described as the polar opposite of someone who "relaxes with friends after a game".

Comment: @Adamant - Also, I'm not that familiar with the films. What do they show about Gwenog Jones?

Answer (score 1):

## We don't know.

It's not mentioned anywhere in the main series, tcc, fantastic beasts, or Pottermore as far as I can tell. On Bertie Botts' [chocolate frog card,](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Bertie_Bott_Chocolate_Frog_Card)  it states that he created them by accident, but that's all we know.

Comment: The card that you linked to doesn't say anything about being created by accident.